# SQLite Hard query to format result

Tags: sql, sqlite, format

I need to write a query that returns elements in the DB in the following format.
Before, It's important to say that I have a *tab where there is a list of folders* and in *another tab there is a list of objects*. Not each folder has an object.
My goal is return this kind of info:

`FOLDER_NAME OBJECT_NAME`

if to the folder corresponds one or more object;
or

```
FOLDER_NAME "NO_ELEMENTS"
```

if to the folder doesn't correspond to any object.

Table structure:

TAB_FOLD:
id_folder, folder_name

TAB_ELEMENTS:
id_folder, id_object, object_name

This is what I tried to write:

```
IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB_OBJECT WHERE ID_FOLDER=X) > 0 )
{
  SELECT ID_FOLDER, ID_OBJECT, OBJECT_NAME FROM TAB_FOLD WHERE ID_FOLDER=X
}
ELSE 
{
  X, "NO_ELEMENTS"
}
```

Comment: Please provide the table structures

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
select f.folder_name, coalesce(e.object_name, 'NO_ELEMENTS')
from tab_fold f left join tab_elements e on f.id_folder=e.id_folder
order by 1,2
```

Comment: What does "1,2" mean? And I'd want to add other fields over e.object_name, example "e.object_name, e.feld_1, e.field_2"...how can I do? Thank you

Comment: order by 1,2 means order by column 1 first, then column 2